# what does a select statement returns if condition doesn't match?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

For example if I have following statement:

```
declare @uid int;
set @uid = (select id from tablename where condition)
```

In this case if the select returns no results, what will the value of `@uid` be?

Comment: trying that yourself could be faster than asking and waiting for answer..

Comment: You could write this a lot easier: `select @uid = id from tablename where condition` ...

Comment: As simple as this question can be, it's useful to have the answer straight clear in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**in simple words it will be null**

I have made simple temporary table to test this

```
declare @temp table 
 (
   id int identity(1,1) not null  ,
   alpha nvarchar(50)
 )

 insert into @temp select 'z'
```

declared a variable `nvarchar type` and get value in this where condition is not meet  then there is null and if you see by print statement then there should be  nothing will be print

```
declare @test nvarchar(50)


 select @test=alpha from @temp where id=70

 insert into @temp  select @test 
 select * from @temp


 print @test
```

**I just insert  this again  to  confirm that there is  null**

Answer (score 2):

**It will return NULL in that case**

Comment: then can integer variable @uid hold this null?

Comment: Yes, it will be null as well.

Answer (score 1):

Do a check, like this:

```
declare @uid int;
set @uid = (select id from tablename where condition)
If @uid IS NULL
  print 'uid is null or not exist'
```

OR, You can set default value in case it return null

```
 If @uid IS NULL
      set @uid = 0
```